# Need to get value from radiolist and run javascript function when page loads

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a radio list where getting one of the radio buttons is getting checked on load based on saved data.  What displays onscreen is dependent on the selected value in the radio list.  I've attached an onclick handler to the list items to show the proper screen based on what is selected.  My problem is running this function or something similar on page load.

I used the onclick handler because of ASP.Net creating the ID names uniquely when the page loads.

Below is my javascript function:

```
function toggleType(item)
    {
        if(item == "Individual")
        {
            $("#individual_info").show();
            $("#business_info").hide();
        }
        else
        {
            $("#business_info").show();
            $("#individual_info").hide();

        }
    };
```

I need this function to run both when the data is loaded when the page is loaded and when the radio list value changes.

If no selection has been made in the database for the radio buttons, then both selections are hidden.  That code is setup in the document.ready function.

EDIT: Added ASP.Net tags

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="fldType" CellPadding="3" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Individual" onclick="javascript:toggleType('Individual')"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Business" onclick="javascript:toggleType('Business')"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Comment: Can you show us your HTML?

Comment: @deweyredman, this ASP.NET code turns out to be the HTML of the Web Page. He is using ASP.NET Web Forms.

Comment: Thats correct.  This code is contained within an ascx control.  The page it is rendered on also contains a master page.  Therefore, the ID becomes ridiculously long and unpredictable.  I know part of the ID string, but it is contained within the full generated ID.  If I was able to determine the ID, I would just call the item directly using the ID.  I've been looking into a jQuery solution, but haven't found anything of use yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  I added a CssClass attribute to the radiolist and updated my function.  Since I have a list index at the end of each item, I was able to determine what was being checked at any given time.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="fldType" CellPadding="3" runat="server" RepeatDirection="0">
<asp:ListItem Text="Individual" onclick="javascript:toggleType('0')"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Business" onclick="javascript:toggleType('1')"></asp:ListItem>
```

Javascript function:

```
function toggleType(item)
{
    if(item == "0")
    {
        $("#individual_info").show();
        $("#business_info").hide();
    }
    else
    {
        $("#business_info").show();
        $("#individual_info").hide();

    }
};
```

Javascript/jQuery Document Ready function to handle the the toggle on load.

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
    $(".toggleEntityType input").each(function ()
    {
        if(this.checked)
        {
            var splitId = this.id.split("_");
            var id = splitId[splitId.length - 1];

            toggleType(id);
        }
    })
});
```

I had to ensure I specified the input element, because ASP.Net puts the class on the span element that wraps around the input node.